# SearchBarController Predicate Causing Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to add a searchBarController into my tableView. I am not getting any errors when I build the app, but when I start typing into the searchBar, the app throws an exception and crashes.

The line that causes the crash is commented below in the very last block of code. Does anyone know what might be going wrong here? Thanks much!

**Relevant Parts of my .h file:**

```
@interface BusinessesViewController : UITableViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, 
UISearchDisplayDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    NSArray *businesses;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSArray *filteredBusinesses;
}
```

**Relevant Parts of my viewDidLoad Method:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    filteredBusinesses = [[NSArray alloc]init];
}
```

**NumberOfRowsInSection Method:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredBusinesses count];
    }
    else {
        return [businesses count];
    }
}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath Method:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BusinessesTableViewCell *cell = (BusinessesTableViewCell *)[tableView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [cell.businessMainLabel setText:[[filteredBusinesses 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }   
    else {
        [cell.businessMainLabel setText:[[businesses 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Predicate and SearchDisplayController Methods:**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"beginswith[cd] %@", 
    searchText];

    //THIS LINE OF CODE CAUSES THE CRASH
    filteredBusinesses = [businesses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
    shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
    [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate is wrong, the *key* is missing. From the other code it looks as if
the objects in `businesses` have a "name" property, so the predicate should be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",  searchText]
                                   ^key   ^operator    ^value
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think I'm getting close here. the name property comes from a JSON response as follows: `[[businesses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]` any ideas on how I would handle that?

Comment: @Brandon: Then the above should work. - Note that `valueForKey:` is usually the wrong method (it is for Key-Value coding), your above code uses `objectForKey:` which is correct.

Comment: OK thank you, it is now only crashing if I enter a letter that is indeed in the tableView. If I enter something that's not in the tableView array, it appropriately says "No Results" any other thoughts on why this may still be crashing?

Comment: @Brandon: Any information on the crash? Messages, stack backtrace? - A wild guess: Try `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"]`

Comment: OK NO MORE CRASHING WOOOOOO. THANK YOU. still acting up, but progress! Thanks!